# How do I configure CircleCI to not install Python dependencies, via circle.yml?

Tags: python, pip, circleci

My project which I build on CircleCI includes a requirements.txt file listing the Python dependencies to install through pip, but I do not want CircleCI to try to install these dependencies. How do I, via [circle.yml](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/), configure CircleCI to not try to install project dependencies?

Comment: Why don't you want it to install the requirements?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because they aren't relevant for the build.

Comment: It looks like CircleCI finds the file automagically; either rename it or look into the `override` setting in the `dependencies` section.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, my current solution is to add a dummy command to dependencies.override, but it doesn't feel very elegant (without a command the override isn't applied)...

Comment: Then... why not *mention* that? This is likely a question for their support, not SO.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, I think this belongs on SO for sure. If noone comes up with a better solution I might write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I have worked around the issue by adding a dummy command to `dependencies.override` in circle.yml, but it's not the most elegant solution...

```
dependencies:
  override:
    - echo "Just overriding CircleCI inferred dependency installation..."
```

Comment: That seems pretty elegant to me. If it works, *what's the problem?*

Comment: @jonrsharpe I find having to add a dummy command inelegant. It also adds an unnecessary build step which can be confusing. Besides, I guess you could make the same argument for any hack, given that it works...

Comment: I could and would; spend your time on stuff that adds value!